# I need information about connecting to a windows server DC with ldapjs and changing user password

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldapjs

is their any documentation for connecting to a windows AD with ldapjs?
I'm trying to change to password with this code and i can't figure out what the issue is.
the bind worked but now I'm getting an npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE...

`var change = new ldap.Change({
    operation: 'add',
    modification: {
        userPassword: 'MyPassword1234'
    }
  });

client.modify('robert@rob.com', change, function(err) {
    assert.ifError(err);
  });`

Comment: You would get better answers if you give a specific problem you are facing. AD uses LDAP to communicate with it, so ldapjs would work with it. AD does have its own quirks sometimes, but that's where you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at the [activedirectory2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) module, which is just a wrapper around ldapjs to handle the quirks for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the windows CA on the AD,

I added to the client configuration tlsOptions = { 'rejectUnauthorized': false }
this alone didn't help to connect using ldaps that's why i set the CA, but now that it works i'm not tucking it.

also was missing a function to encode the password.